# conda.yaml file: what does channel means and why there needs pip if dependencies already exists？

Tags: conda

I am studying MLFlow, which uses conda to help set environments and dependencies. In following conda.yaml file /1/, I have three questions:

1. What does channel means? Why there needs anaconda? What is default channel?
2. In dependencies section, there is pip, pip is package management tool. If there is dependencies key word, why there is again a need for pip? Does pip install dependencies' dependencies.
3. name: flower_classifier, does means environment name is flower-classifier?

/1/

```
name: flower_classifier
channels:
  - defaults
  - anaconda
dependencies:
  - python==3.6
  - numpy==1.14.2
  - keras==2.2.4
  - pandas
  - pip:
    - tensorflow-gpu==1.10.0
    - mlflow
    - click==6.7
    - scikit-learn
    - pillow
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### 1 Channels

This refers to where Conda, the environment management tool, is going to look to find the declared dependencies.  Currently, the `defaults` channel will search all URLs under the https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/ directory.  The `anaconda` channel is a subset of this that only includes `pkgs/main`, `pkgs/free` and `pkgs/pro`. It is unnecessary to include both these channels since `defaults` covers them both.  See [the Anaconda documentation on repositories](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-repositories/).

### 2 Why pip?

Not all Python packages are available as Conda packages. Some might only available through PyPI, or may be released there first.  By including `pip` in the dependencies, that Python-specific package manager will be included.  Listing packages below `pip` in the hierarchy, indicates that `pip` should be used to install those packages.

### 3 Environment Name

Yes, the environment name will be `flower_classifier` by default. However, the `--name | -n` flag can be used to override this if you happen to not be that into flowers.

```
conda env create -f conda.yaml -n my_env
```

Comment: One more question, How user could know which Python package is included in Conda package, which is not included?

Comment: @user84592 You can search Anaconda Cloud. For example, [searching for "click"](https://anaconda.org/search?q=click), you can see this doesn't have to be installed from PyPI.

Comment: @user84592 it may also be worth noting you can use `conda search click`, but this only searches channels you have added (or add with a `-c <channel>` flag).

Comment: How to generate the yaml file?

Comment: @Catbuilts Use `conda env export > environment.yml` to generate the yaml file for the currently active environment.